# Взять данные из XML файла и поместить их в переменную javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlparser

Всем привет. Поставил я себе задачу взять курс валюты с сайта Центробанка и вывести его у себя на сайте.
Имеется XML файл (http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp?date_req=). Вот только я про XML вообще ничего не знаю. Как мне с помощью JS получить значение тега(я же так понимаю там информация в теги заключена), и присвоить это значение переменной.
И самое основное с чем у меня проблема, как мне содержимое этого файлы переместить на свой сайт. Ну то есть подключить этот XML или что с ним делать? Если подключить нужно, то как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Раз с xml не очень хочется работать вы можете преобразовать его в обычный JS объект и работать с ним. Могу посоветовать xml2js ([ссылка npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js)).

Делаете GET запрос получаете, ответ, полученный ответ передаете в метод parseStringPromise() у экземпляра xmlDate.Parser(), возвращает промис результатом выполнения, которого будет объект с которым, я думаю, вы уже умеете работать.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import xmlDate from 'xml2js';

const parser = new xmlDate.Parser();
axios
  .get(
    `http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp?date_req=`
  )
  .then((response) => {
    parser.parseStringPromise(response.data).then((result) => {
      const yourVar = result.ITEMS[0].ITEM[0]; // работаете как с обычным js объектом, (здесь какие-то рандомные свойстав написал)
    })

  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: Я так понимаю для этого нужен сервер?

Comment: Ну вы это на клиентской части можете делать, ну а чтобы отдавать статику вам нужен какой-то веб-сервер, это да.

Comment: ну вот ваш вариант у меня почему то не работает, можете растолковать как получить XML. Вот например есть у меня комп с подключением  к инету. Я в браузере открываю страницу, запускается скрипт, и этот скрипт должен подтянуть XML файл с конкретного интернет адреса, и взял из него определенные данные. Либо просто как взять этот самый XML из инета. Я просто тупо не понимаю как мне подключиться к XML файлу, взять данные которуе есть на странице я могу с помощью getElement*, а как взять файл XML который физически не находится в папке сайта?

Comment: Для этого и существуют http requests, я в примере использую axios для их реализации. Что касается axios, что 'xml2js' это пакеты, которые устанавливаются либо через CDN либо через npm.

Comment: но что бы эти пакеты работали сайт должен лежать на сервере?

Comment: не обязательно, можете и на локальной машине своей все это разворачивать.

Comment: ну так я копирую ваш код а в консоле выдает ошибку: Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module